# Gradle 'AppName' project refresh failed Cause: hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: android

```
Gradle 'AppName' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: hostname in certificate didn't match: <jcenter.bintray.com> != <*.services-exchange.com> OR <*.services-exchange.com> OR <services-exchange.com>
```

1. 1.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

   2.First ，I want change the version of  the  package(the 'appacompat-v7' and 'design'),then I change it to 25.0.3,the IDE give me a tip,next I change the targetSdkVersion to 25  and compileSdkVersion. The gradle didn't work.

   3.

   ```
   dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'
   ```

   4.

   ```
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "AppName"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:appacompat-v7:23.0.3'

      compile 'com.android.support.design:design:23.0.3'
       compile 'com.squareup.oktppp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
       complie 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
       complie 'com.android.recycleview-v7:23.0.3'
       complie 'com.github.bumptech.glide:3.7.0'
       complie 'com.wdullaer:masterladateimepicker:2.5.0'
   }
   ```
2. How can I repair it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo error. You should use this and change compile to implementation if you're using Android 3.0 and higher

```
compileSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Your applicationId should reflect your package name. Confirm this from your manifest.

Use 23.1.1 for dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

And this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

Comment: it is a AndroidStudio2.1.1

Comment: You can still use compile then.

Comment: but my SDK manager  haven`t  download  the  27.1.1 sdk build tool

Comment: compile 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7:appacompat-v7:23.0.3' check your typo. It is appcompat not appacompat and fix your applicationId too

Comment: Dude, fix your applicationId. You'll get the correct thing from Manifest if you didn't temper with it too.

Comment: Thanks  for  your  help. I found  the mistake.I  change  my gradle version and  change  something  package.